# Is there any way that the values here be converted to another variable and not string?

Tags: arduino-uno, string, memory-usage

```
int val1 =(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0]);
int val2 =(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1]);
int val3 =(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2]);
int val4 =(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3]);

String valA=String(val1);
String valB=String(val2);
String valC=String(val3);
String valD=String(val4);
uID=valA+valB+valC+valD;
```

The function above with `mfrc522.uid.uidByte[x]` is from the `MFRC522.h` Library by Miguel Balboa and it is initialized as byte there. But when I initialize the val1 to val4 as byte, the desired number doesn't appear. I don't intend to print the uID to serial (as someone may suggest that to readily print to serial as it converts it automatically to some ASCII strings), but instead in the `client.print()` of the Ethernet library along with other codes. I want to save it into another "greater" variable in terms of speed and memory allocation. The Arduino community warns about the use of `String` as it uses additional decoding which is not needed as well as may crash Arduino and make Arduino run out of memory. And somehow, I experience some lagging or hanging in the serial, which I thought maybe due to the use of Strings variable. Please help me. I've read some `sprintf()` concatenations and `free()` but not well documented, I'm quite confused on their explanations. :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to print the UID to serial. Have you tried using "mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(mfrc522.uid);" ?

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf()` is a nicer way to do that (imo), however, there's nothing wrong with what you've done-- if you don't have a ton more code, I'd continue to use it.

It's simple and that's a lot more important that speed most of the time. Also, the likely memory usage isn't enough to worry about.

In my experience, once I got past 1500 bytes SRAM (dynamic) memory usage, I ran into trouble. But my projects have a ton of code. I've read through the `String` class code and it's totally reasonable-- you're not likely to experience lag there.

[My bet is that the lag is due to the timeout period](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout), try making it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The UidByte[] is a 10 character array, loaded with the tag ID (this is an RFID reader) by the library.

Your code is attempting to put a character value into integer variables.

What you mean to do (I think) is to read the string as a number - this would be `val=atoi(mfrc522.uid.uidByte)` which relies on there being only numeric data in the ID string - or at least, will only read the leading numbers (if any). Also, there are 10 characters in the string - if you want to limit this to 4 you will need slightly more code.

If you have a tag on which you set the ID then this is usable, for your tags at least; but you can't rely on numeric uid's being universal.

If your intent is, as you say, to include it in a longer string, then the overhead of atoi is completely unnecessary and you should just handle it as a string. I think you have misunderstood the warnings about strings, there isn't a problem just handling short chunks of fixed-length data as strings, and I think you are inadvertently causing trouble by extra conversions.

Comment: The poster's concerns are based in real issues with dynamic memory allocation on small systems, and while they may not occur here is what could hopefully turn out to be a reuse-in-place allocation case, it is also not necessary to allocate a bunch of dynamic Strings to accomplish this goal at all.  If the size of the intended result is known or reasonably bounded, byte/character values can be directly written to appropriate positions in a C string.